# Can i install in some way ODBC driver in a raspberry?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, odbc

Questions:

- There is any mini board/pc/rasp that suports SQL Server driver in Linux ?
- Which pc/device should i use for a php with MSSQL ?

I am trying to use a raspberry pi 3 b+ with a connection to a SQL  for a local server, i tryed to install the driver and i saw online that raspberrys are ARM and the driver for linux is only available in amd64 base.

Comment: You could try building [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org/) from source on the ARM board (or emulator?) and see if you get an ODBC driver to use.

Comment: i tried to do it but some how i cant connect to my SQL Server, the SQL server is not in the raspberry , it is on another computer(same network) and in my php web server i connect to it. In windows it works great with the driver, but in raspberry it doesnt suport and idk why...Microsoft being microsoft...